# SQL Server 2008 2mb Limit for XML?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to output a long XML result from SMSS.

When I right click on the results and 'save results as...', I can only get a 2mb file?

I have changed the settings in SMSS via Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid, for XML data to be unlimited.

However, it still seems to be truncating my XML results?

So, how can I bypass this problem and output my XML result to a file?

Thanks

Comment: What about when you click on them in the grid and it opens up in the new window. Is it truncated then or is it only save to file that is affected?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen this before and this is a limitation of the Results grid. Try outputting your results directly to a file and see what happens.

Comment: There are three buttons on the SQL Editor toolbar, "Results to Text", "Results to Grid" and "Results to File". Choose "Results to file" and run your query.

Answer (score 1):

may this option can help you

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM database.dbo.table FOR XM L RAW" queryout c:\Archivo.xml -Syourserver -T -c -r -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart the SMSS after making the changes, it works fine.

SMSS via Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid, for XML data to be unlimited.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb4H9.png)

Comment: Insert the image directly to the answer, please. Does your answer hold in for he SQL server 2008?